# Add Geolocation filter to twitter stream through spark streaming in Java

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I want the tweets related to particular geo location alone. After googling around, I found that this can be achieved by adding extra methods/functionality to TwitterUtils and TwitterInputDStream classes. But I am unable to do so as these are final classes.

Help me on How can we achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Write your own GeoTwitterDStream?

Answer (score 0):

This is the best answer I could find to do this when creating the stream. However, with this filter, we are filtering the tweets after receiving them. I think there is a way to filter before receiving them by supplying the filter to the twitter api. This code has been verified to work and comes from: 
http://www.michael-goettsche.de/?p=19#return-note-19-4

```
    JavaDStream<Status> tweetsWithLocation = twitterStream.filter(
            new Function<Status, Boolean>() {
                public Boolean call(Status status){
                    if (status.getGeoLocation() != null) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
    );

    JavaDStream<String> statuses = tweetsWithLocation.map(
            new Function<Status, String>() {
                public String call(Status status) {
                    return status.getGeoLocation().toString() + ": " + status.getText();
                }
            }
    );
```

Comment: Please describe your question, you want to do in scala, java or python ?
And do you have list of locations you want to filter out or have just 1 location to be filtered out.

Comment: I'm answering the original question. I am also saying that I think there is a way of telling twitter that you only want tweets with geo info instead of filtering after you receive them. I assume that the original questioner would want to do this in Java and so would I. Do you have an answer?